# SSH agent forwarding configured and (seems to be) working but github still asks for user & password

Tags: git, github, ssh

I followed the github guide (https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding) to ssh agent forwarding.

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Attempt to SSH in to github
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide
shell access.
```

This command works on both local & server. But when I try a git pull (or other github related command), on the server, it still asks me for my login & password.

Is the problem could come from that I don't use the same username on local & the server ? Or did I miss something else ?

- local : ubuntu 11.10
- server : debian 6

Comment: Are your remotes configured using `git@github.com...` or using `https://...`? SSH agent forwarding only affects the former.

Comment: Thx @Chris ! That was the problem (git@github.com on local, https on server). Do you want to write the answer or should I do it ?

Comment: I've added this as an answer. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH agents only affect remotes that use the SSH transport.

Make sure your remotes are configured as `git@github.com:user/repo.git`, not `https://github.com/user/repo.git`.