# git using public ssh asks for password on windows

Tags: git, key, public

I'm trying to do a git clone a repo on windows using a public ssh key using the instructions:
https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey

It still asks for a password.
- I was able to run ssh-add after running ssh-agent
- when I type

> ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id-rsa.pub

, it shows me the finger print
- when I type

> ssh -T git@github.com

, it shows my user name. I also read somewhere that I should ensure that GIT_SSH is not set. That is the case.
I've also added to ~/config the following:

```
Host *
    User git
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\id_dsa.pub
```

Any ideas how to make git work without asking for a password?

Comment: How did you "run `ssh-add` after running `ssh-agent`"? Can you include all the commands? Also, have you taken a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17848593/456814)?

Comment: Is your remote configured for SSH (e.g. `git@github.com...`) or HTTPS (`https://github.com/...`)? Remotes configured for HTTPS will never connect using SSH. You can see your remotes with `git remote -v`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH agent forwarding configured and (seems to be) working but github still asks for user & password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906267/ssh-agent-forwarding-configured-and-seems-to-be-working-but-github-still-asks)

Comment: Chris, you're right. Instead of https url, I should have used git@github.com:repo. Then I can clone without a password.